# ngOptions error when Angular version is upgraded from 1.2 to 1.4+

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is error

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'select', required by directive 'ngOptions', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$compile/ctreq?p0=select&p1=ngOptions
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:68:12
    at getControllers (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:8103:19)
    at getControllers (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:8110:24)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:8250:33)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:7637:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:7641:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:7641:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:7641:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:7641:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:7641:13) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12416(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9203invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8748nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8246compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7512boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7656controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8273x @ angular-route.js:936$broadcast @ angular.js:16238(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:619processQueue @ angular.js:14634(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14650$eval @ angular.js:15916$digest @ angular.js:15727$apply @ angular.js:16024done @ angular.js:10511completeRequest @ angular.js:10683requestLoaded @ angular.js:10624
```

I was trying to work on the datepicker and I found a simple coffescript based script and then I converted it to js

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/h95uu6b5/8/

When I am changing the Angular's version to 1.4+ it isn't working.

I used the same code in my angular controller directly like this and the error came in which is pasted above.

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = {
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    language: 'fr',
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 0
};
$scope.date = '2000-03-12';
```

Comment: There are some breaking changes in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Maybe is your code affected by one of these?

Comment: Your question is so unclear. You didn't post any `ngOptions` as suggested in *title*. In addition to your **jsfiddle** shows a lot of errors as soon as it starts, you're using angular **1.0.8** there.

Comment: @RwamDev I will go through it and see if I can find something.

Comment: @developer033 I was shell shocked as well because there wasn't any `ngOption` there but the error is the same.

Comment: @developer033 I have updated the fiddle link, it is working fiddle link now. But still it wont work for Angular 1.4+, I changed the version from fiddle's control.